# Can André–Quillen homology detect the property of being Gorenstein?

Tags: homological-algebra, cohomology

Let $(A,m,k)$ be commutative noetherian local ring.

Can one detect if $A$ is a Gorenstein ring from the [André–Quillen homologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9%E2%80%93Quillen_cohomology) $H_n(A,k,-)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No" if you want a standard vanishing result, and "no up to now" if you are thinking in another kind of characterization (see however for a related result: Garcia-Soto, Ascent and descent of Gorenstein property, Glasgow Math. J.
46 (2004) 205–210).